# Dynamically add controls in ASP.NET: factory pattern design pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I am trying to understand how I can get this JSON data into a factory pattern design pattern. The JSON data below have two `MeetingPollingQuestionType` one for `LongAnswerText` and one for `MultipleChoice`. From that would I need two class `ConcreteStrategy` `LongAnswerText` and `MultipleChoice`? The MeetingPollingPartsValues are different two. LongAnswerText just has a label control but MultipleChoice has radio controls

> Any help would be great, The Goal is to create a MVC form with MVC controls like labels textbox and radio list.

```
[
    {
        "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 2,
        "MeetingPollingQuestionType": "LongAnswerText",
        "MeetingPollingId": 3,
        "SequenceOrder": 1,
        "MeetingPollingParts": [
            {
                "MeetingPollingPartsId": 2,
                "Type": "Question",
                "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 2,
                "MeetingPollingPartsValues": [
                    {
                        "Type": "label",
                        "QuestionValue": "This is a long question",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 3,
        "MeetingPollingQuestionType": "MultipleChoice",
        "MeetingPollingId": 3,
        "SequenceOrder": 2,
        "MeetingPollingParts": [
            {
                "MeetingPollingPartsId": 3,
                "Type": "Question",
                "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 3,
                "MeetingPollingPartsValues": [
                    {
                        "Type": "label",
                        "QuestionValue": "this is a multiple choice question",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "MeetingPollingPartsId": 4,
                "Type": "Image",
                "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 3,
                "MeetingPollingPartsValues": [
                    {
                        "Type": "Image",
                        "QuestionValue": null,
                        "FileManagerId": 14552,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "MeetingPollingPartsId": 5,
                "Type": "Answers",
                "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 3,
                "MeetingPollingPartsValues": [
                    {
                        "Type": "radio",
                        "QuestionValue": "Yes",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "radio",
                        "QuestionValue": "No",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "radio",
                        "QuestionValue": "Abstain",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Goal
MVC form view

this would be the base for the LongAnswerText.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.LongAnswerText)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.LongAnswerText, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

this would be the base for the MultipleChoice

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.MultipleChoice)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.QuestionValue, item.Value, false)
</div>
```

App

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LongAnswerText LongAnswerTextParts = new LongAnswerText();
        var control = LongAnswerTextParts ()

    }

    interface MeetingQuestionInterface
    {
        string Label(string target, string text);
    }
    
    public class LongAnswerText : MeetingQuestionInterface
    {
        public static string Label(string target, string text)
        {
            return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);
        }
    
        public static string TextBox(string target, string text)
        {
            return String.Format("<input  for='{0}'>{1}</input>", target, text);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Strategy, like all patterns is a way of doing something, so what do you mean by _get this JSON data into a Strategy design pattern_? You don't put data into a pattern, you use a pattern to solve a problem. Please explain what you are trying to do, and we will be able to help. Specifically, what problem do you think the strategy pattern will solve for you?

Comment: @avrohom-yisroel I updated the post with the goal,  I am trying to solve the problem of creating MVC controls base on that JSON/ controls like labels textbox and radio list.

Comment: Re [Strategy Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999356/design-patterns-strategy-design) - Q: So you wish to read a JSON "UI definition file", and dynamically create Razor page UI elements accordingly, correct?  Look here: https://www.codemag.com/article/0401041/Dynamically-Adding-Controls

Comment: If you can use ASP.Net Core, you might also consider using a [Dynamic Component class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.dynamiccomponent)

Comment: I would think you'd actually use a factory pattern here, where the factory takes a `MeetingPollingQuestionType` and returns the UI/MVC appropriate for the question type. The way I've done this in the past is to have the class responsible for drawing itself though.

Comment: I think that is what I am looking for . Would I create a interface meetingpollingquestion and pass that view model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to parse the data into their corresponding classes, so you can use the values accordingly in your MVC application in some sort of OOP way.

Well, here's a start. If you have the json of the data, you can use `Newtonsoft.JsonConverter` to deserialize it into some classes. A custom `JsonConverter` will be needed since `Newtonsoft` does not have enough information to deserialize to an interface:

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IMeetingPollingQuestion[]>(
        "JSONSTRING", 
        new MeetingPollingQuestionConverter());
    
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}

public class MeetingPollingQuestionConverter : JsonConverter
{
  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(IMeetingPollingQuestion);

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        var type = obj["MeetingPollingQuestionType"].ToObject<MeetingPollingQuestionType>();

        return type == MeetingPollingQuestionType.LongAnswerText ?  
        obj.ToObject<LongAnswerText>() : (object)obj.ToObject<MultipleChoice>();
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
  }
}

public abstract class IMeetingPollingQuestion {
    public int MeetingPollingQuestionId {get; set;}
    public MeetingPollingQuestionType MeetingPollingQuestionType {get;set;}
    public int MeetingPollingId {get; set;}
    public int SequenceOrder {get; set;}
    public MeetingPollingPart[] MeetingPollingParts {get; set;}
    public virtual string Label(string target, string text) => $"<label for='{target}'>{text}</label>";
    public abstract string Control(string target, string text);
}

public class LongAnswerText : IMeetingPollingQuestion {
    public override string Control(string target, string text) => $"<input  for='{target}'>{text}</input>";
}

public class MultipleChoice : IMeetingPollingQuestion {
    public override string Control(string target, string text) => "...";
}

public class MeetingPollingPart {
    public int MeetingPollingPartsId {get; set;}
    public MeetingPollingPartsType Type {get; set; }
    public int MeetingPollingQuestionId {get; set;} 
    public MeetingPollingPartsValue[] MeetingPollingPartsValues {get; set;}
}

public class MeetingPollingPartsValue {
    public MeetingPollingPartsValueType Type {get; set;}
    public string QuestionValue {get; set;}
    public int FileManagerId {get; set;}
    public string FileName {get; set;}
    public string FileData {get; set;}
    public string FileType {get; set;}
}

public enum MeetingPollingQuestionType {
    LongAnswerText, MultipleChoice
}

public enum MeetingPollingPartsType {
    Question, Image, Answers
}

public enum MeetingPollingPartsValueType {
    label, Image, radio
}
```

Here is the running example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ylIOQJ

Comment: Thanks where would I add the image tag for the MultipleChoice? Would it go into the interface? Or would it be better in the class MultipleChoice?

Comment: you mean the image within the type of MeetingPollingPartsValue? you have several choices the MeetingPollingPartsValue object could be another abstract class and you could have concrete classes for radio, label and image and those classes could have their own specific properties. As long as you define how to parse it correctly in the ReadJson() everything is valid.

Comment: Oh wait, you mean MeetingPollingPartsType.Image? I think since that only exists in the multiplechoice one.. I would add it there.

Comment: Is that without the override ? Just public string ?

Comment: Also what type is obj?

Comment: You need to override things that are defined as abstract on a parent class or may choose to override things that are virtual on a parent class. Basically, virtual things are optionally overridable, abstract is not optional.

Comment: obj is of type JObject. You can verify this by calling .GetType() on obj. Here's the documentation for [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

Comment: Thanks so in IMeetingPollingQuestion that has a label and control but for image would i need that in the interface ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you define something in the abstract class. Both concrete classes will inherit it. If you want something specific for the concrete class (MultipleChoice), I would define it there.

Comment: I was thinking the json that has This is a long question
And this is a multiple choice question would be bind to the label control .

Comment: MeetingPollingPartsValues is an array and the label exists in the parent object. You would need to define a method that queries the correct MeetingPollingPartsValues with the type label if you want to do that. That could be done in the abstract class as a method (same functionality for both implementations). Optionally, you could make it virtual, in case that each of the implementations requires something specific.